# Windows SBS 2008 Remote Webmail Access

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-sbs-2008

We have a Windows 2008 SBS set-up and running, we would like to allow our users to access there Exchange Mail account remotely.

I've set the router up to allow all port 80 and 443. The Exchange webmail seems to be the application OWA in SBS Applications and it's all there, however when I navigate to

```
https://remote.URL.co.uk/OWA/
```

I get

> The connection has timed out
>   The server at remote.URL.co.uk is taking too long to respond.

What would this suggest is wrong?

Update =======
It works on the network (From the server-cant get at the machines atm): https://localhost/owa/, IIS is running and working (We run a couple of development sites on there) both 80 and 443 are forwarded by the router. Will check to see if windows firewall is doing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your browser shows a connection timeout I would suppose that the HTTP request doesn't reach your server's IIS.

You could check:

- Did you forward TCP ports 80 and 443 to your machine's IP address?
- Does the server's built-in firewall block the requests?
- Is IIS running on the server?
- Is there some other device (firewall) or service (antivirus) blocking the ports?

What happens if you try to reach the OWA site from within your network?